# Woocommerce 3.0 Variations Product Gallery: pictures don't change when I select the variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce 2.14.6, if you had a variable product, you could select the variation you wanted, and the picture in the gallery would automatically change to that variation (assuming you had already set the image). With new Woocommerce 3.0, this doesn't happen anymore. I'm using the most current version of wordpress, and I haven't found this problem solved elsewhere, despite searching for weeks. My co-worker suggested this: https://createandcode.com/broken-photo-gallery-and-lightbox-after-woocommerce-3-0-upgrade/ but it didn't work. When we downgrade woocommerce, on top of the concern of using out of date technology, it won't let us "update" our products pages, so that isn't a workable solution. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution as long as I'm okay getting rid of the rest of the gallery.

"MrSamSeen commented on Jun 28
[FIX FOUND]
I replaced the "product-image.php" file in the theme folder (wp-content/themes/[path-to-theme]/woocommerce/single-product) with the one found in the woocommerce folder (wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product)And it works.Please backup your current files before you do thispreferably the theme developer should do this in their next theme update, but above solution worked for me.I just followed the instructions in this Fixing Outdated WooCommerce Templates" ([source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14154))

Here is another resource I found, but didn't inspect, as I found an answer already.
https://answers.themler.io/questions/135442/woocommerce-product-variation-image-not-showing